# 100vh exceeds height of mobile browsers, so content scrolls and/or is cut off

Tags: android, html, css, ios, viewport

I have a layout that is contained within the viewport. The content height shouldn't exceed the height of the viewport.

This works fine on desktop in Chrome/Safari/Firefox. But I'm having issues on iOS Chrome/Safari (and I imagine Android too) where the content displays taller than the viewport and requires a scroll. I assume this is due to the address bars.

This occurs on two elements:

- The main content area which has `100vh` scrolls.
- A `fixed` bar on left of the page which should not scroll at all. The logo appears off the top of the page - so I assume it exceeds the height of the browser. This actually has `100vh` set on the `width` as it's rotated 90 degrees.

I've read up on a few older articles but nothing seems to work. Code is added to post but I've also created a Codepen so it's easier to view on mobile: https://codepen.io/moy/pen/popxXXe

```css
/* #GLOBAL */

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1,
p {
  margin: 0 0 24px;
  padding: 0;
}

/* #HEAD (left column) */

.page-head {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 64px;
  padding: 0 24px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: -64px;
  left: 0;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
  width: 100vh;
}

.site-logo {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 32px;
  order: 1;
  stroke: black;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  width: 32px;

  svg {
    overflow: visible;
  }
}

.contrast {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1 1 0%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

/* #GRID */

.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.grid__item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 24px 24px 0;
  margin-left: 64px;
}

.gallery {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 24px 24px;
  text-align: center;
}

.gallery img {
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: top center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

/**
 * Side-by-side view for wider devices.
 */

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .grid {
    background-color: black;
    flex-direction: row;
    column-gap: 2px;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0 64px;
  }

  .grid__item {
    background-color: white;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100vh;
    margin-left: auto;
  }

  .gallery {
    padding-top: 24px;
  }

  .gallery img {
    height: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    object-fit: initial;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

/* #FOOT (right column) */

.page-foot {
    margin-left: 64px;
    padding: 0 24px;
}

.swiper-pagination {
    display: none;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {

    .page-foot {
        border-bottom: 2px solid black;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        display: flex;
        height: 64px;
        padding: 0 24px;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: -64px;
        left: 0;
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
        transform-origin: top left;
        width: 100vh;
        left: auto;
        right: 0;
        transform: rotate(90deg);
        transform-origin: top right;
    
        p {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }
    }
    
    .swiper-caption {
        flex: 1 1 0%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="page-head" role="banner">
  <div class="site-logo">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 64 64" height="32" width="32">
      <defs>
        <clipPath id="a">
          <circle cx="32" cy="32" r="31" fill="none" />
        </clipPath>
      </defs>
      <circle cx="32" cy="32" r="31" fill="none" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" />
      <g clip-path="url(#a)" fill="none" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2">
        <path d="M16.19 58.57V5.43L31.94 32 47.69 5.43v53.14M31.94 32v31.49" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" />
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <p class="contrast"><a href="#" class="contrast__link"><span class="contrast__switch"></span><span class="contrast__label">Contrast</span></a></p>
</div>

<div class="grid" role="main">

  <div class="grid__item">

    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

  </div>

  <div class="grid__item gallery">
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/700/1000" />
  </div>

  <div class="page-foot" role="contentinfo">
    <p class="swiper-caption">Caption Goes Here</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Try using 100% instead of 100vh.

Comment: I can't use that unfortunately because I need to apply `100vh` to a width!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using javascript may help?
`element.style.height = window.offsetHeight`
I haven't tried this so I'm not particularly sure.